# How would Doctor Strange be affected by the Accords?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war, doctor-strange

How would Doctor Strange and the sorcerers be affected by the Sovokia Accords?

In the comics, Dr. Strange was neutral in the Civil War, except for a brief time when he gave sanctuary to heroes on CA's side. Also, the sorcerers aren't on Earth 24/7.

Comment: The accords affect and regulate anyone with powers or enhanced abilities. Is there a reason you believe they would/should be exempt?

Comment: @phantom42 better-hidden?  They've had this whole protecting-in-secret thing going on.  As long as no Sokovia-accord-signatory government knew about the sorcerers, they would be *de facto* exempt even if they were covered *de jure*.

Comment: No real reason. Just that they might spend a lot of time away from Earth, like the GOTG.

Comment: I would like to see somebody try to enforce the accords on Drax and Rocket  if they ever land on Earth. I imagine it going something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8t5tqqm3KE

Answer (score 14):

## **In theory, either not at all, or in exactly the same way as all the heroes based in America. In practice, not at all.**

117 different countries, mainly European, American and African, signed the Sokovia Accords.

There are 196 countries on our planet Earth. If we assume for the sake of argument that made up Marvel countries like Wakanda and Sokovia replace existing countries rather than simply add on to them (there’s a finite amount of land, after all), that leaves 79 countries, a lot of which are likely Asian, who haven't signed the Sokovia Accords.

If Nepal *is not* one of the countries to have signed, it would mean that Strange is able to legally act as any hero would before the Accords existed, back in the Phase 1 / 2 days. He would have complete impunity.

If Nepal *is* one of the countries that signed, then legally he would be "regulated" in the same way as all the other heroes based in those countries.

Of course, that's speaking legally, and doesn't take into account the approach of "Screw the accords, I have magic". Nobody but the sorcerers knows where he is, he can teleport, control time, even travel to other dimensions if he wants to. Governments can say and do what they like, but they won't be getting a hold of Doctor Stephen Strange any time soon.

Comment: Legally, even if Nepal was not a signatory, he'd probably be subject to the Accords when operating in any country that *was* a signatory, just as local laws apply (for example) Brits (who can buy their own alcohol at 18) may not be allowed to drink when in places where the minimum age is higher (say, 21).  In practice, yeah, they probably don't even know he exists and even if they do how exactly are they going to enforce the Accords?  Points for recognising the difference between his restrictions *de jure* and *de facto*.

Comment: Many of the sorcerers may call Nepal their home, but Strange appears to be a US citizen. Even Inhumans who may/may not have been citizens of any particular country appear to be subject to the Accords.

Comment: _"a lot of which are likely Asian"_ Why's that, then?

Comment: Of the 117 countries, notable member to sign are listed as the USA, UK, Germany, France, Sokovia, Wakanda etc. All of them are either, American, African or European countries. Not a single Asian country is listed, not even important players like China, India or Japan. I'm certainly extrapolating a bit, but it looks to me that many Asian and Southern American countries were among the 79 that did not sign the accords, which makes it more likely that Nepal didn't, either. I don't have direct evidence to say one way or the other, who did or did not sign. I'm just playing the probabilities.

Comment: Strange is a US citizen, which is why he goes on to protect the New York sanctuary (even though he refuses at first). Because he is in New York and is a US citizen, he would be affected by the Accords.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Simply because we know that Sokovia replaces a European country, which means most of Europe signed it, and Wakanda is in Africa, which means most of Africa must have signed it. Therefore, the next continent with the biggest amount of countries is Asia, which just happens to contain the country where our Doctor has been training.

Comment: @DragonSkull777: _"Wakanda is in Africa, which means most of Africa must have signed it"_ I don't follow. Why?

Comment: Does this mean that the rest of the sorcerers are affected by the Accords as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Wizards would claim that they are a higher authority than any or all of Earth Governments. So the Accords do not apply to them. Though I think that Strange would push for incorporating his group with an enlightened global, representative governing entity.